# Any way for Excel to evaluate a number in a text string?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a cell containing:
    January
    15,5%
    (204 cases)

I want to use conditional formatting and fill this cell if its smaller than the value in another cell:
    5%

This would be an easy task if the first cell only contained the value 15,5%. But is it there any way I can make Excel evaluate just the percentage in a cell?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there always a comma? And always a subsequent percent sign? You could then find where these characters are and evaluation the number in between. Better yet, as mentioned, split out the information into separate columns.

Comment: Is comma the decimal separator in your regional settings?

Comment: Yes, splitting would probably be the easiest solution, just wondered if there was any other way. Yes, comma is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

try peeling out the percentage with,

```
=--trim(mid(substitute(A1, " ", rept(" ", len(a1))), len(a1), len(a1)))
```

compare it to anything you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the string `January 15,5% (204 cases)` in `A2`, you can get the percentage by means of the following formula

```
=MID(A2,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789")),SEARCH("%",A2)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789"))+1)
```

1. Use the `SEARCH` function to get the position of the first number
2. Use the `SEARCH` function to get the position of the percentage sign
3. Use the `MID` function to get the percentage `15.5%`

No matter you have decimal or not, and no matter if the decimal sign is a comma or a dot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeeped's formula, you can also use:

`=MID(A5,SEARCH(" ",A5)+1,SEARCH("%",A5)-SEARCH(" ",A5))`

And if the `comma` decimal-point is native to your data, but not to you or your user's systems, you can wrap the formula in the `NUMBERVALUE` function:

`=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A5,SEARCH(" ",A5)+1,SEARCH("%",A5)-SEARCH(" ",A5)),",")`

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly to extract the number to another cell. I tried to use it directly in conditional formatting with formula, but it doesn't seem to work. =MID(G27;SEARCH(" ";G27)+1;SEARCH("%";G27)-SEARCH(" ";G27)) < $C$27